# Is it possible to eavesdrop http response?

Tags: security, encryption, server, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I am new in network security area, now I am designing a REST web api.

The question is that could http response and request be eavesdropped?

If it is impossible, then I don't need encrypt the response json file and the request parameter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [su] and [security.se] are better suited for questions like this.

Comment: Without https, eaves dropping on either request or response is easy. See Fiddler for example http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to eavesdrop an http request and even tamper and modify it before reaching the server.

Comment: then what about the http response?

Comment: Modifying http responses is not that critical in my opinion. The problem is that one could bypass the client side validation and inject bad code that the server might be vulnerable to.

Comment: Therefore you should not rely on client side validation.

Comment: I think you need to send and receive data over https rather than http.

Comment: Http is plaintext, therefore when intercepted (easy), can cause alot of problems.

Comment: Sorry that I mentioned a bunch of things.

Comment: To summarize, almost everyone can eavesdrop a network and see the whole communication between the client and the server. But you need your packets to  be in non plaintext. Therefore use https rather than http.

Comment: hi, thanks for all of these explanation, so should I say that https response is safe that no one can eavesdrop it?

Comment: They can eavedrop it but they wont be able to modify it since it is not in plaintext.

Comment: so either they will not be able to decrypt the text of the response, right?

Comment: Only the legitimate client would be able to decrypt it since he would have a certification (how https works).

Comment: How is this answer upvoted/accepted? It barely constitutes an answer

Comment: @scrowler I elaborated on the answer in all these comments. Anyway you can answer a more breif one if you like

Answer (score 1):

http sends/receives data in clear text, use https (ssl) if you want it to be encrypted